# CSS transition not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a div #im1 with initial position **left:-300px;**
When a button **.abtme_link** is clicked the javaScript changes it's position to **443px;**
It's working on every other browser than Firefox; I've seen some other posts on this matter but can't seem to make it work;
One of the thread concluded that css transition doesn't work on Firefox, If that's the case; is there a workaround?

```
#im1{
    width:400px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-300px;
    transition:all .9s ease .5s;
    -webkit-transition:all .9s ease .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .9s ease .5s;
    -o-transition:all .9s ease .5s;
    -ms-transition:all .9s ease .5s;
}

$('.abtme_link').click(function() {
        $('#im1').css('left','443px');
    });
```

Comment: can you produce a jsFiddle for this?

Comment: Please add html here and create fiddle

Comment: In my mozilla its working fine and animation is supported by mozilla too. Can u pls provide the link where u have read that ?

Comment: It works fine in Firefox [in this example](http://jsbin.com/votow/1/edit?html,css,js,output). As an aside, the [moz and opera prefixes aren't really needed anymore](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). There is no prefix for IE and the prefixed properties should be *before* the non-prefixed.

Comment: Check your version of Firefox, iitum studant. You may need to update.

Comment: @roman - it's [been in firefox since version 4](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions). He would really need to update if he is still using 3!

Comment: Oh nice. In that case, something else in iitum studant's testing must be the cause.

Comment: I've created this http://jsfiddle.net/4yypfhc2/
Here it works fine.But in my webpage it doesn't work. Also I've tested it in every other browser and it works fine. And when I click the button, the transition happens i.e. it goes from -100 to 443 but the transition animation doesn't happen. Could it be because of my jQuery imports?
These are my imports:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: @iitumstudant - there will be something else interfering with it. Open your webpage in firefox, right-click and "Inspect Element". Trigger the click function and then select the div in the inspect view and see what CSS is interacting with it. Feel free to post a link to your site as well.

Comment: @ It seems jquery conflict issue. Are you getting any error in console for the same ?

Comment: @misterManSam : I've tried that. The 'left' property changes from -300 to 443 and the inspect tab also shows the transition property listed but doesn't show transition effect. It's funny because I have another div and I'm changing it's width from 0 to 100% and it's showing the transition effect in Firefox. 
I apologize I can't post my website link as it contains personal information.

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati : No, console is not showing any errors.

Comment: @iitumstudant - you will need to recreate the problem in a sample that you can share... preferably [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net). Without that we are unable to help as it cannot be re-created.

Comment: @misterManSam I've found a solution. I just put a delay before the execution and it's working. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I've found a solution,

I've added a delay function in JS and it's working fine. Don't know why or how but it's working.

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $('.im1').css('left','443px');
        },10);
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense. The delay accounts for the CSS transitions delay. You could also try removing the `.5s` delay here: `transition:all .9s ease /*.5s remove*/`

Comment: Yes, I'd do that. Although I still don't understand why I had to use manual delay in mozilla and not in other browser. 
But again, atleast it's working now and I can finally got to sleep. :)